# Why will my action listener not work/

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

Why will this actionlistener not display a pop up box when you click the button "Rock"? Solutions?

```
ClickListener cl1 = new ClickListener();    
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JButton Rock = new JButton("Rock");
    Rock.addActionListener(cl1);
    panel1.add(Rock);
    this.add(panel1);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
private class ClickListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == "Rock"){
            int AI = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I have been clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `e.getSource()` returns the reference of the component that was pressed. You need to do `if(e.getSource() == Rock)`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23298192/2587435)

Comment: RPSFrame.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                        if(e.getSource() == Rock){
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable Rock
  location: class RPSFrame.ClickListener
1 error

Comment: @James You need to declare the JButton Rock in order to have the correct scope to "see it" in your ClickListener class. IMO, you should declare the ClickListener class as an inner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if("Rock".equals(e.getActionCommand()){
```

As long as you don't explicitly set the action command for the button, `e.getActionCommand()` will return the string text you pass to it's constructor.